# Jmeter script error while ruuning selenium webdriver script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I have wriiten following script in jmeter for my chatbot application.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get('http://interview.erainfotechbd.com:5003/');
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("chat bot opended");
var userName = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@name="nickname"]'));
userName.click(); //clicks search field
userName.sendKeys(['tahashin']); //types word "blazemeter" in field//saves search field into searchField
var mobileNumber = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@name="mobile"]'));
mobileNumber.click(); //clicks search field
mobileNumber.sendKeys(['01913498919']); //types word "blazemeter" in field//saves search field into searchField
var loginButton = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//button[@id="Enter"]'));
loginButton.click(); //clicks login button
var selectInterview= WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//form[@id="myFormInt"]/input[1]'));
selectInterview.click();
timeouts.pageLoadTimeout(600, timeUnit.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
var returnedAnswer=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@class="form-control"]')).getText();
var enterValidNumber= WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@class="form-control"]'));
enterValidNumber.sendKeys('01676912613'); 
var sendMessagebutton= WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//button[@id="sendMessage"]'));
sendMessagebutton.click();
timeouts.pageLoadTimeout(600, timeUnit.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

After running the script it is showing following exception:

```
Unable to load class: com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.oauth.OAuthSampler
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.getJARPath(Plugin.java:202) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.detectInstalledPlugin(Plugin.java:108) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.detectInstalled(Plugin.java:97) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:86) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem$1.run(PluginManagerMenuItem.java:41) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    ... 16 more
```

I have configured chromedriver correctly. what is the possible cause to give this error? why Oauth sampler is needed?

Answer (score 1):

[OAuth Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/OAuthSampler/) will not work with your current JMeter version, if you need to use this sampler for other tests - you will need to downgrade your JMeter version to [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31/)

[image]

If you don't need the OAuth Sampler - just delete `jmeter-plugins-oauth-x.x.jar` from the "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation and the error will go away after JMeter restart